# Changing status via entries list in one locale also (unexpectedly) changes status in other locale(s)

Tags: entries, localization, status

I'm not certain if this is expected behavior but if so the user experience is confusing/unexpected:

When viewing a list of entries in the control panel, swapping between locales shows the expected statuses--either enabled or disabled--for each entry. Accordingly, example, an entry that is enabled in English but disabled in Spanish, is properly displayed as such. However, making a change to the status when switched to either locale applies the status to *both* locales, rather than just the selected locale.

This seems to indicate that adjusting statuses through the entries list applies only to the entry's master enabled/disabled status, not the selected locale's status (which was my expectation). Should this be the be case? I found out the hard way by switching to my Spanish locale, selecting all entries, and then setting their status to disabled. Switching to the other status showed that they too had been disabled. Bummer.

Any thoughts or similar experiences? Did I miss something in the docs?

Cheers.

Comment: This probably falls under 'feature request' or 'bug report'. I would suggest sending the issue to P&T or posting it on Craft Google+.

Comment: I agree with Douglas... This is simultaneously a bug report and a feature request. I'd highly recommend contacting P&T directly to get their thoughts on the matter. (support@buildwithcraft.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On localized sites, each entry has two statuses: the primary entry status (the big “Status” lightswitch field at the bottom of the sidebar) and the locale-specific statuses (the small lightswitch field beside the currently selected locale).

For an entry to be enabled, both of those lightswitches have to be turned on. But only one of them has to be turned off for it to be disabled.

The confusion here is because the entry index page doesn’t communicate *why* an entry is disabled - whether it’s because the entry’s primary status is disabled, or just because the current locale’s status is disabled.

So, when you have an entry whose primary status is disabled, but its locale-specific statuses are enabled, enabling the entry from the index page is going to end up enabling it across all locales, not just the one you’re currently looking at.

If this is a common problem for you, you may want to go into your section’s settings and set all of the default locale statuses to disabled. So you will always have to explicitly enable a locale’s status before it starts showing up for that locale.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Brandon. I'll work around it. It would be nice, though, to have the ability to bulk change locale-specific statuses as the UI would seem to indicate is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this is confusing.

If you are editing the entry, you can change the status per/locale by selecting the locale in the box in the upper right corner, and then using the lightswitch next to the selected locale.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, I'm well aware of the per-entry statuses and this doesn't address the issue at hand.

Comment: It does address your issue, @cliquenoir. Because this is the only way to set the per locale status on an entry.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree. This was not a how-to question. I was already aware of how to change locale-specific statuses from within the entry which is how this originated. My question instead was directed at the UI which, as some would agree, does introduce the potential for unexpected results.